# Set a macOS version in a Vapor project

Tags: vapor

I'm starting a new vapor project and one of my own swift packages has a min deployment target of macOS 10.12.

The swift build tool itself accepts specifying the target version as follows:

```
swift build -Xswiftc -target -Xswiftc x86_64-apple-macosx10.12
```

Is it possible to specify the macOS target when building with the vapor toolbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *should* be able to pass arbitrary arguments through the vapor toolbox, but to be honest I'd just bypass it and use `swift build` directory - the toolbox doesn't add anything

Comment: I didn't think about building a Vapor project directly with Swift. That works fine. Also to generate the Xcode project with the correct deployment target, I use `swift package generate-xcodeproj --xcconfig-overrides Package.xcconfig` with `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.12` in the Package.xcconfig. Thanks Tim for the support (and for working on Vapor ;) ) !